# I'm using Shared Preference to save the whole application data instead DataBase, is it ok?

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences

I'm working on an application that helps people to save information about their working days in the job.

The user enters Start Date and End Date for each working day, and the app calculates his salary and hours he have worked this month.

Instead of saving this information in a `DataBase`, I save the information in `Shared-Preferences`. for instance, I save his salary in this way (Wage is an `EditText`):

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
editor = sharedPreferences3.edit();
editor.putString("Wage", wage.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

I'm pretty sure it's great to save a figure like a wage in `Shared-Preferences`. But in order to save the Enter and Exit Date for every working day, I should use `DataBase`. However I used `Shared-Preferences`.

The working days are separated by `@`, for example, a string of working days will be like -

```
09/27/2015 13:02 - 09/27/2015 20:02 @ 10/27/2015 10:15 - 10/27/2015 16:15.
```

With the char `@` I can take extract the information and do whatever I need with it.

What I'm trying to ask - Is using, `Shared-Preferences` instead of `DataBase`, ok?

Comment: Why are you using Shared-Prefs, ease of use or what?. If you're going for ease of use then have a look at Snappy-DB. Easy to implement and the ease of use is about the same as SharedPrefs, but its faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to store data different that preferences and by preferences i mean a fixed number of different values that can change its value but its not going to grow more than its expected.

You are using preferences in a way that not the expected. I cant tell you the cons of doing it or what problems will you fight because of this.

I recommend you using the internal SQLite for this, or... you could use a simple local file and serialize a class containing the data you want to save.

Both options will be better than using preferences.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short :

1- you can store your user input / data into a local database if you data is big .

2- you can use shared preferences to store data if your data is relatively small.